# VSTS build error when Get sources: TF14045: The identity c2f86e2b-d649-4685-8e45-4b0e819a0153 is not a recognized identity

Tags: visual-studio, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

VSTS build suddenly has errors when Get source. 
[image]

Always the same error occurs after I delete the _work folder. Even after delete the agent and create a new one, it still fails but with a different identity number...
What happened?

Comment: What's the version of your build agent? (Agent queues=>Select a queue=>select a agent=>Capabilities=>Agent.version). Try to download the latest version of agent, then configure it. On the other hand, try to delete the related workspaces (ws_1_237) on build agent.

Comment: It is a bug and under investigation, will be fixed.